# Creating a path to an asset dynamically

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

The issue is how to get Vue to render the correct path for an asset, if the path to the asset and the assets name is passed through as a props.

**Explanation:**
When using a Vue component... if passing in props which contain a path and a file name of an asset to be loaded

```
export default{
   name: 'NewComponent',
   props: ["path","file"],
   computed:{
      calculateCompletePath (){
         return this.path+""+this.file;
      }
   }
}
```

If using something like the above in a manner such as:

```
<template>
  <div>
     <video>
        <source :src="calculateCompletePath" type="video/mp4"/>
     </video>
  </div>
</template>
```

How can you get the src portion to render correctly - e.g Vue generates its own string referencing the media folder for example

> /media/movie.6ac43bcf.mp4

---

*Side note:*
I've read somewhere there is the possibility to using `require (<<asset>>)` but that doesn't seem to work if used on the **computed** function e.g. `return require (this.path+""+this.file);`

---

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: Where is the mp4 file located in your folder structure? Is it under `src` folder or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this document for a detailed explanation on how to resolve static assets: 
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports

I think the problem is that your asset(in this case an mp4 file) is not located in your computer's `/media` folder.

See these 3 points for a better understanding: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules

- If your `media` folder is located under the root folder(`/`), then, the computed value `/media/movie.6ac43bcf.mp4` will work.
- If your `media` folder is under `src` folder of the app, your computed property should return `@/media/movie.6ac43bcf.mp4`
- If your `media` folder is somewhere else, then you should create a proper path using `@/` or the `./` symbol to reach the file correctly.